# MySQL: what's the maximum number of arguments allowed within the IN() function for one query?

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, select

What's the maximum number of arguments allowed within the  `IN(., ... ,.)` function?

With another words, what's the maximum N for such query to be valid

```
SELECT * FROM  mytable WHERE mycol IN (a1, a2, ..., aN);
```

Comment: There is not *per se* a maximum, but there might be a maximum query length -- and there might be a better way to write the query without an `IN`.